# Browser scolls to bottom when opening new tab in Chrome Selenium using Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am running a task in Chrome with Selenium in C#. The first/main tab stays open throughout this task. I then open a new tab. Do some stuff. Then close that tab. This might repeat 15-20 times per execution of the task.

I tried several options, for opening a new tab, including SendKeys and other "solutions" found on here, but injecting the below JavaScript into the webdriver is the only one that actually works for me.

```
var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);return a;
```

The problem is, that every time I open a new tab, the first/main tab scrolls to the bottom, then the new tab is opened. The web page in the first/main tab loads more stuff every time it scrolls to the bottom. This is problematic for several reasons which aren't relevant to the question.

My question is, why does this JS code scroll to the bottom of the first/main tab, and how do I stop it?

Comment: After executing the above script what is the next action you are doing . As you are returning a . Is it click on newly created a tag ? Your script is adding this tag at the bottom of page and selenium may be bringing it in focus before clicking . I would directly call a.click() in above script var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);a.click()

Comment: Ok. So to be more specific. What exactly happens is as follows. 1. First tab is in focus. 2. Inject the Javascript. (The JS scrolls to the bottom of the page in the first tab, then opens the second tab. The first tab is still in focus) 3. Then I SwitchTo the new tab. Open a URL. Parse the HTML. Close the tab. 4. SwitchTo back to the first tab.   REPEAT    Does that help?  But I will try your solution, and let you know if that fixes it.

Comment: Try using the javascript posted in below answer . I tested it in chrome .In the script we are directly calling the click .It will not scroll to bottom of page now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly click on the 'a' tag using javascript and do not return a .

```
var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);a.click();

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("var d=document,a=d.createElement('a');a.target='_blank';a.href='';a.innerHTML='.';d.body.appendChild(a);a.click();");
```